# Unable to install VBoxGuestAddition 5.1.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

Im trying to install VBoxGuestAddition 5.1.2 on my Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed all packages required by running following command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms module-assistant linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo m-a prepare
```

and then I selected  *Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image* and run the Vboxguestaddition installation. However, i received this error

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.1.2 Guest Additions for Linux...........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.1.2 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules.
Failed to set up service vboxadd, please check the log file
/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log for details.
Press Return to close this window...
```

I then checked the `/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log` file

```
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Please check that you have gcc, make, the header files for your Linux kernel and possibly perl installed..
```

When I reviewed the `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log` file, I noticed that `/lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/build/include/linux/version.h` is missing and the kernel configuration is invalid

```
grep: /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file 
or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/build 
SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j1 modules
Makefile:227: ================= WARNING ================
Makefile:228: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
Makefile:229: 
Makefile:230: If you are building an individual subdirectory
Makefile:231: in the kernel tree, you can do like this:
Makefile:232: $ make path/to/dir/you/want/to/build/
Makefile:233: (Do not forget the trailing slash)
Makefile:234: 
Makefile:235: If you are building an external module,
Makefile:236: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
Makefile:237: ==========================================
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
...
...
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:288: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1655: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/vbox.0' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.footer:84: recipe for target 'vboxguest' failed
make: *** [vboxguest] Error 2
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Im not sure how to fix this problem. I've already had kernel (5.3.0-42-generic) + header, gcc installed but I have no idea why the `/linux/version.h` header is missing or why the kernel configuration is invalid. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using an old virtualbox version?

Comment: @user1974 I didnt really keep up with the latest version. In fact,  i was surprised once i found out 5.1.2 was released in 2016! I downloaded this version back in 2017 but didnt really use it afterward. Last year,  I installed it back with the old installer and it worked fine so i thought everything would be fine but now i learned the lesson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like VBoxGuestAdditions 5.1.2 is not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04. I tried to install my virtual box manager to the latest version and download the latest VBoxGuestAdditions (16.0.4) and now it works.